# null pointer exception at FragmentPage

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am getting a null pointer exception error at runtime.I am mentioned the error line in below coding.I am posted the codes relevant to that.I am unable to solve this.Anybody can help me if you know how to solve these.Thank You.

**StackTrace:**

```
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247):    at com.qrme.FragmentPage.highlightCell(FragmentPage.java:473)
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247):    at com.qrme.FragmentPage.moveToNext(FragmentPage.java:455)
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247):    at com.qrme.FragmentPage$10.onItemClick(FragmentPage.java:351)
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-03 05:14:58.729: E/AndroidRuntime(18247):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**FragmentPage.java:**

```
public class FragmentPage extends Fragment {

    GridView gridTable;
static LinearLayout ll;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentxml, container, false);

        initialize(rootView);
        clickEvents();

        return rootView;

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

    tablelist = DatabaseQueryHelper.getInstance().getContentTable(pageId);
        System.out.println(tablelist);
        System.out.println(pageId);
        if (tablelist != null && !tablelist.isEmpty()) {
            CustomeTableAdapter tableAdapter = new CustomeTableAdapter(
                    getActivity(), R.layout.frame_table, tablelist);
            gridTable.setAdapter(tableAdapter);

        } else {
            ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(tableVisible && !getactivitytable)
            {
                if (tablelist == null
                        || tablelist.isEmpty()
                        && sharedpreference.get_sharedvalue(
                                QRMConstants.VERSION).equals("1.0")) {
                    showDialog();


                }

            }
        }

    }


public void initialize(View v) {


        gridTable = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewTable);
        ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        gridTable.setDrawSelectorOnTop(true);

    }

public void moveToNext(int nextposition) {

        highlightCell(nextposition); --->455 th line error
        ispaused = false;
        play(nextposition);

    }

gridTable.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    final int position, long id) {
                if (tablelist != null && !tablelist.isEmpty()) {
                    ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    player.reset();
                    currentSelection = position;
                    moveToNext(currentSelection); --->351 th line error
                } else {
                    ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

public void highlightCell(int position) {

        for (int i = 1; i < tablelist.size(); i++) {

            gridTable.getChildAt(i - 1)
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border); ---->473 rd line Error

        }

        gridTable.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.dusty_grey));

    }
```

**fragmentxml.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayoutControll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagebuttonLast"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_previous"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridViewTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearlayoutControll"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:rotationY="180" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is this ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: public void initialize(View v) {


        gridTable = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewTable);
        ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        gridTable.setDrawSelectorOnTop(true);

    } what is ll in this line

Comment: `static LinearLayout ll;` now I am edited and added that.@NaveenTamrakar

Answer (score 0):

i think it is because this line returns null

```
gridTable.getChildAt(i - 1)
```

I don't know what tablelist contains but basically i guess that if you try to take items from the gridview which are not drawn on screen they will be null.

Comment: Using log.d I get it like this `Checkandroid.widget.GridView{b3f36478 VFED.VC. ......ID 23,23-457,685 #7f0a0022 app:id/gridViewTable}`

Comment: Using Log.d to log what?

Comment: I used   `Log.d("Grid Highlight","Check"+gridTable);` and get it in logcat like `D/Grid Highlight(29749): Checkandroid.widget.GridView{b3f36478 VFED.VC. ......ID 23,23-457,685 #7f0a0022 app:id/gridViewTable}`

Comment: of course because gridtable is not null but since you iterate through all his items trying to retrieve them, the ones which are not drawn on the screen will be null. it would be useful see your adapter code